# redux thunk won't work - actions should be an object use custom middleware

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? I keep getting actions should be an object use custom middleware error. It works if I try to return like { type: 'SOMETHING' } on the fetchAdmins(), but according to the redux-thunk docs I should be able to return a function that has dispatch as params and that's what I did but maybe I missed something.

#### store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import allReducers from './js/reducers/index.js';

const Store = (initialState) =>
            createStore(
                allReducers,
                initialState,
                applyMiddleware(thunk)
            );
export default Store;
```

#### RootAdmin.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { fetchAdmins, addAdmin, deleteAdmin } from '../actions/actions.js';

@connect(
    state => ({
        admins: state.admins
    }),
    dispatch => bindActionCreators({
        fetchAdmins: fetchAdmins,
        addAdmin: addAdmin,
        deleteAdmin: deleteAdmin
    }, dispatch)
)

class RootAdmin extends Component {
    // ...codes
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchAdmins();
    }
    // ...codes
  }
};

export default RootAdmin;
```

#### actions.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export function fetchAdmins() {
    console.log('fired'); // this gets fired.
    return (dispatch) => {
        console.log('not fired'); // not fired.
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCHING_ADMINS' });
        console.log('fetching'); // won't even log
        axios({
            url: '/api/fetchAdmins'
        })
        .then(res => 
            dispatch({ type: 'FETCHED_ADMINS', payload: res.data })
        )
        .catch(err => 
            dispatch({ type: 'FAILED_FETCH_ADMINS' })
        );
    };
}
```

#### reducer-admins.js

```
export default function (state = null, action) {
  const { payload } = action;
  let newState = {...state};
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCHING_ADMINS':
        newState = {...payload};
        newState.log += '\nfetching admins';
        console.log('fetching admins');
      return newState;
      break;
  }
  return state;
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please add related reducers also for FETCHING_ADMINS

Comment: added reducer although it doesn't get fired.

Answer (score 0):

It's not your action creator causing the issue... I believe the issue lies in your mapDispatchToProps

```
@connect(
    state => ({
        admins: state.admins
    }),
    dispatch => bindActionCreators({
        fetchAdmins: fetchAdmins,
        addAdmin: addAdmin,
        deleteAdmin: deleteAdmin
    }, dispatch)
)
```

Note that you're returning an object from the state mapping function, but in your dispatch you're returning the result of bindActionCreators which can be an object or a function...

```
@connect(
    state => ({
        admins: state.admins
    }),
    dispatch => ({
        actions: bindActionCreators(Object.assign({}, fetchAdmins, addAdmin, deleteAdmin), dispatch)
    })
)
```

then access your method as this.props.actions.fetchAdmins();

Comment: Hi thanks for replying! I tried the code but I get the error this.props.actions.fetchAdmins(); is not a function. I tried to log this.props.actions but it was empty {}.

Comment: I tried to `import * as actionCreator from '../actions/actions.js';` then `dispatch => ({ actions: bindActionCreators(actionCreator, dispatch) })` but I get the same error as I did before. I got a feeling that my middleware isn't working? :/

Comment: With your original code. Can you log dispatch before you dispatch your fetching admins type? Have you confirmed you’re getting the dispatch method pass through. I use ES6 in my project as well but have had issues with arrow functions and thunk. We ended up using return function(dispatch) { ... } rather than return (dispatch) =>

Comment: anything inside `return (dispatch) => {}` doesn't get fired. I updated the action.js in post with console logs for a proper visual representation. I tried `return function(dispatch) {}` as well and it's the same.

Comment: Do you have a github repository for this? If you look for me on there and add me as a contributor I can look at it a little closer. I personally don't use @connect and have only used connect as a higher order component. I'm still quite certain that the issue is in the way you're binding dispatch to your action creators but can't know for sure without a more complete picture.